# Occasional, limited usage of someone else's Apple watch to collect data

Tags: apple-watch

Occasionally, I'll have a need to get some biometric data (heart rate, calories burned, etc) during exercise. I would like to use my girlfriend's apple watch to do this.

I don't need to sync the data anywhere (it would be nice but manual transfer is fine for now) and maybe just as importantly, I guess I don't want my data getting mixed in and mucking hers up.

By borrowing her watch from time to time, is it possible (as in will I get accurate readings) for me to get the data I seek?

And is there a way to flag my exercise sessions (while wearing the watch, of course) such that the data is not read into whatever the watch or phone uses to track her movements?

Comment: Down vote & no comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watch uses age, weight, sex, etc. that are recorded in the Health app to calibrate its measurements. The biometric measurements may not be accurate to you for this reason.

You cannot prevent the Watch from recording biometric measurements to the Health app without disabling those measurements entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of afraid both of those would be the case